# Node.js | Tracking HTTP requests with Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I am trying to look at the HTTP requests made by a page, upon searching I find lots of ways to do this with Python (https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/ - there are others)

However I am using Node.js to do my crawling and can't seem to find anything related to it using Node.js

My script is only simple, but here it is

```
(async function scrape() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
  try {
    await driver.get("***");
    let html = await driver.getPageSource();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await driver.close();
  }
})();
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You should always give traceback to show where your code doesn't work.